# Executing maven-easyb-plugin as part of the integration phase instead if the test phase

Tags: maven, maven-2, bdd, easyb

Is it possible to execute the maven-easyb-plugin as part of the integration phase instead of the test phase? I would like to run the easyb tests once project is deployed to a webserver.

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.easyb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-easyb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <storyType>html</storyType>
                        <storyReport>target/easyb/easyb.html</storyReport>
                        <easybTestDirectory>src/test/stories</easybTestDirectory>
                        <jvmArguments>-Xmx512m -Dwebdriver.driver=firefox</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case it would be:

```
<execution>
    <phase>integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

in your's plugin config.